# Can't update data in to mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem.
I'm trying to make a CMS, but I cant update my data through php.
They are variables and it didn't accept my query, but when I used static values it updated.
Here's my code.
Error I have is $menu1 is undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="author" content="Robert Michalski">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CSS</h1>
    <h2>+HTML 5</h2>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Edycja menu
            <input type="text" name="menu1" placeholder="menu1">
            <input type="text" name="menu2" placeholder="menu2">
            <input type="text" name="menu3" placeholder="menu3">
            <input type="text" name="menu4" placeholder="menu4">
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="save">
    </form>
    <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "wia27";
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "UPDATE menu SET menu1='$menu1' WHERE id=1";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
    ?>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h3>box</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </article>
        <div class="ads">
            <div class="little_ad">
                Box1
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Robert Michalski 2016 &copy;
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: *"$menu1 is undefined"* - So, define it.

Comment: When I did define it, it's still unknown.

Comment: `$menu1 = $_POST['menu1'];` and follow the same method for your other inputs. and use `!empty()` against it with a conditional statement.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['menu1'])){

$menu1 = $_POST['menu1'];

}` etc.

Comment: I tried, but "Undefined index" indicative on $menu=$_POST['menu1'];

Comment: You're doing `$menu` but using `$menu1` in your query. Use the same one you want to use and see my other example above.

Comment: It works, It defines. But still not update at all. Do I use a good way?
      $sql = "UPDATE menu SET menu1=$menu1 WHERE id=1";

Comment: Don't forget to check whether the form is submitted by using `if(isset($_POST['button'])` before connecting to the database.

Comment: `menu1=$menu1` you need quotes around it `menu1='$menu1'`.

Comment: Even with quotes nothing changed

Comment: I did solve it. It was just about <form action="index.php"> it should be empty. Thanks for help !!! ;) @Fred-ii-

Comment: you're welcome Robert. Glad to see you solved it, *cheers*